# How does Hibernate map setters/getters to properties?

Tags: java, hibernate, boolean, mapping

In my database table I have a `CHAR(1)` column that can either have Y or N as its content (CHECK constraint). I defined a String property in Java and a String-based setter in my class. Furthermore, I added a `@Transient` setter/getter with boolean arguments for convenience.

My expectation was that Hibernate uses the String-based setter/getter for database access. However, at runtime I get an IllegalArgumentExceptions and a type mismatch between boolean and String.

So, based on what properties does Hibernate do the mappping? Method names? Argument names? Argument types? Is it OK to use `final` in the setter or can this cause rumors? Does it make any difference, if my property has a different name than my table column?

```
private String foobar = "N";

public void setFoobar(final String foobar) {
  this.foobar = foobar;
}

@Column(name = "FOOBAR")
public String getFoobar() {
  return this.foobar;
}

@Transient
public void setFoobar(final boolean foobar) {
  this.setFoobar(foobar ? "Y" : "N");
}

@Transient
public boolean isFoobar() {
  return (this.getFoobar().equals("Y") ? true : false);
}
```

Comment: You should try with @Column(name = "FOOBAR", columnDefinition="CHAR")
public Character getFoobar()

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem happens because you use the same name for both `String` and `boolean` properties (i.e. getters and setters) - try to use different names for them.

Alternatively, you can use a built-in type that handles this conversion automatically - just annotate your `boolean` property with `@Type(type = "yes_no")`.